# Subjective grading scale: US vs Europe

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, gpa

I currently hold a Bachelor's degree in Pure Mathematics and my plan is to pursue a Master's degree in the USA. However, I'm a bit worried about the possible non-injective grading scale transition that exists between the USA and European universities.

What I mean here is - majority of the sites out there postulate that ultra-high GPA of `4.1+` is required to get admitted into top USA universities. I've also read about the *scaled GPA* where the topmost grade is `4`, so this might be the case of my university.

Another issue was that getting a good grade, for example 8,9,10 (almost impossible) out of 10 points, was really, really hard. Moreover, I remember myself happy getting 4 out of 10 points in a specific subject. On the other hand, I know some friends of mine who study Humanitarian Sciences and get top grades all the time... So is there some difference when comparing the fields of study?

Comment: What *exactly* is your question?

Comment: A common way of translating grades is with percentiles.